# How to attach a popover to fontawesome icon

Tags: jquery, backbone.js, twitter-bootstrap-3

Ok, so, I have an text input box. I also have fontawesome icons in the textbox.

I am trying to trigger a popover (from twitter bootstrap 3) box upon a click on one of the fontawesome.

Nothing I do seems to work.

However, the catch seems to be that the file backbone. Or at least .hamlc

Here are the contents of that file:

```
    %form#new-message-form{:name => 'message'}
      .input-group.input-group-unstyled
        %input#content.form-control.chat-input{:name => 'content', :type => 'text', :placeholder => 'Your message ...'}
        %span.input-group-addon
          %i.fa.fa-paperclip
          %i.fa.fa-star
          %i.fa.fa-clock-o
      .chat-send
```

One of the things I tried to do was to attach an ID to the star, like this:

```
   `%i.fa.fa-star#example`
```

If I attach that ID to anything else outside of the .hamlc file, it works.

But in the file above, it doesn't. I have no clue if it's due to the fact that it's backbone, etc. (I don't know backbone)

This is the jquery that I attached: (not my jquery, just something I ripped off online to test it)

```
  $(document).ready(function() {
     $("#example").popover({
        placement: 'bottom',
        html: 'true',
        title : '<span class="text-info"><strong>title</strong></span>'+
            '<button type="button" id="close" class="close" onclick="$(&quot;#example&quot;).popover(&quot;hide&quot;);">&times;</button>',
    content : 'test'
  });
});
```

I know for a fact that the jquery works above since I tried it outside of the first file.

But I need to attach the popover to the star *in* this file.

Any advice?

**EDIT**

Just to clarify things, the first file ... here is its file directory in case that makes any difference in troubleshooting why it doesn't work *in this*file ...

`app/assets/javascript/templates/messages.new.hamlc`

And just to clarify, this is a ruby on rails app with backbone, and coffeescript in it.

Hence the file type being .hamlc ...

If I should approach trying to get the popover to work on a fontawesome icon *in* the textbox in a different way, please let me know. I'm seriously at my wits end.

**EDIT 2**

I think it has to do with the fact that the file that has the input textbox is not receiving the file that has the jquery in it ...

the path of the jquery file is `app/assets/javascript/template.js`

and the file in which i'm trying to call the popover in is as stated above:

`app/assets/javascript/templates/messages.new.hamlc`

Answer (score 0):

Change the code to this and it should work.

```
...
%i.fa.fa-star.pop
...

$(document).ready(function() {
     $(".pop").popover({
....
```

Edit: Working, [CodePen](http://codepen.io/cmd430/pen/bdgmjy)

Comment: I don't really like this solution since I have other fa-stars on the same page. That being said, I tried it. It worked on the other star, but not on the star in the input box, which is the one I want it to work on.

Comment: tried your alternate solution. again, it didn't work. it's as i said in my post, i think it has to do with the file type, ie, .hamlc ... not sure ... it works elsewhere in the app, but not in this page. at all.

Comment: are you getting any errors or is it just not working ?

Comment: it's like what I keep saying in my post. it works else where in the app, just not in the input box in the file posted above

Comment: hmm ill have to think for a bit then, cant think of any reason it wouldn't be working off the top of my head right now

Comment: it has to do with the directory acess, i think. that's why it worked in other areas because they're in different directories. i'm not sure how to get this jquery rendered ... will post the directory path of the jquery file ... that has the function posted above ...

Comment: have you properly got jQuery included in the page ?